# Android error : Refractoring Cannot be Performed

Tags: android, android-studio

I have got this error when I code this in Android Studio:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
       return ArrayListFragment.newInstance(position);
    }
```

[image]

How to solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look carefully your error message, you're trying to refactor the support library !

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to refactor a default android library file for which you do not have source-code ?

From the error it seems you are doing refactoring on FragmentPagerAdapter.java with is a support library file and not your source code.